# How to pass JSON array view controller in Xcode using swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I can pass values from a simple created dictionary array (dictCategories), however, when I try to pass data in from my JSON array (var orders = Order) it does not work. I get the error:

"Instance member 'row' cannot be used on type 'IndexPath'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?"

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let detailsVC = segue.destination as! SelectedViewController
        let selectedRow = tblView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row
        
        //detailsVC.statusVar = Array(dictCategories.values)[selectedRow]
        
        detailsVC.statusVar = orders[IndexPath.row].order_status[selectedRow]
    }
```

Comment: `let selectedIndexPath = tblView.indexPathForSelectedRow!; detailsVC.statusVar = orders[selectedIndexPath.row].order_status[selectedIndexPath.row]`? But I would use a `guard let` or `if let` instead of using `!` (force unwrap that might cause a crash).

Comment: @Larme Thank you, it comes up with the error: Cannot assign value of type 'Character' to type 'String'

Comment: What line is giving you the error? Where is the type `Order` defined? The bit `orders[IndexPath.row]` should probably be `orders[selectedRow]` instead, but it's a bit hard to tell what you are doing since you don't provide much info about the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var selectedItem:Int?
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedItem = indexPath.row
    print(selectedItem)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    if let detailsVC = segue.destination as? SelectedViewController
    {
        detailsVC.statusVar = orders[selectedRow].order_status
    }
}
```